# Different iPhone5 screen height value returned using different xcode versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, height, iphone-5

I am preparing view which has an image in background and which image is to display (i.e. one is for iPhone4 and one for iPhone5) is decided at runtime using api `self.view.bounds.size.height`.

when I run application using xcode 6.1, it return 568.0 value as height and when I run using xcode 7 in same device, it returns 480.0 value all the time.

I want to know this issue is due to xcode variants or I am making any mistakes. Ask me for any information for issue.

Check link here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5572

Comment: try with `self.view.frame.size.height`

Comment: Add splash screen for all devices . some times such type of issue arrives due to not added splash screen. and if possible please post screen shot of both variation for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use launch images, but you do have a Launch Screen (nib or storyboard) then it will synthesize your launch screen at install time. It isn't an issue for iPad because up until the iPad Pro was introduced, iPad has only had 1 virtual screen size (768x1024) and thus didn't need anything to differentiate fullscreen support. With the iPad Pro you will need a Launch Screen to support the new screen size (and you need Launch Screens to support multitasking on iPad in general).

[image]

Comment: I am using launch image, but still problem is there. Do I need to reset launch image in xcode 7? Is there any issue with sdk 8.0 (previous one with xcode 6.1) and 9.0 (currently in xcode 7)?

Comment: Using image from asset catalog? I also had issue but after setting launch image everything went fine.